# How do I draw with inverted color in graphicsmagick?

Tags: graphicsmagick

I use graphicsmagick to add text to photos; but I'm having problems selecting the proper color for my text.

With graphicsmagick I can use a command such as this

```
convert -fill yellow -draw "... text ..." ...
```

to write yellow text on an image.

Is there a way to write with color inversion instead? What I mean is: Where the underlying picture is black, I want the text to be white; where the underlying picture is white, I want the text to be black; where the underlying picture is a certain color, I want the text to be in its complement color.

**EDIT**

Please note that "No, it can't be done" is a perfectly good answer to this question if what I want is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-compose Difference` to overlay your desired text:

**Original:**

[image]

**Then create a text gif.:**

`convert -background transparent -fill yellow label:Rose label_white.gif`

[image]

**Then compose them together using `difference`:**

`composite -compose Difference -gravity North label_white.gif rose: compose_diff.gif`

[image]

You can find more compositing info [here](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#difference).